# How did I still lose with 1 piece advantage?

Tags: opening, theory, endgame, positional-play

Throughout the game, I thought I had a positional and piece advantage, but I STILL LOST!

What did I do wrong? (using Ruy Lopez btw)

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 
2. Nf3 Nc6 
3. Bb5 Nf6 
4. Nc3 a6 
5. Bxc6 dxc6 
6. O-O Nxe4 
7. Nxe4 Bg4 
8. h3 Bh5 
9. g4 Bg6 
10. Nc3 Qd6 
11. Re1 O-O-O
12. Ne5 f6 
13. Ng6 hxg6 
14. d4 Rxh3 
15. Kf1 Rh1 
16. Kg2 Qh2 
17. Kf3 Qh3 
18. Ke2 Re8 
19. Kd2 Re8xe1 
20. Qxe1 Rxe1 
21. Kxe1 Qg4 
22. Be3 Bb4
```

At this point, I surrendered because I'm at a positional disadvantage, my knight is pinned and my rook is still undeveloped.

I know one weakness of using Ruy Lopez is that your left side develops slowly, but damn! Where did I make a mistake? Was I just unlucky?

**EDIT 1:**
OMG I just realized he baited my king-side pawns to open up for an attack! >:(

I should've read this article earlier: [Keeping Your Castled King Safe](http://chess.about.com/od/tipsforbeginners/a/Keeping-Your-Castled-King-Safe.htm)

Comment: After `19.Be3!` instead of `19.Kd2??` you win easily. That was the only mistake you made. Other moves are less precise, **but still good enough** to ensure victory. Best regards.

Comment: Gah! You're right!

Comment: Actually, I am not so sure it's an easy win.  After several minutes, Stockfish gives White a slight advantage (1.2) and says  1.... Rh2 2.Kd2 Bd6 3.Ne2 Qxg4 4.Rh1 c5 5.Rxh2 Bxh2 6.c3 Rd8 7.Kc2 cxd4 8.cxd4 Kb8 9.Rc1 Bd6 10.Kb1 Re8 11.Qd3 Qe4 12.Qxe4 Rxe4 13.Rh1

Comment: I agree with @Tony Ennis, after `19.Be3` white is a piece up, but is under attack, I don't see an easy win here.

Comment: There are a number of blunders in the game, but I would really just focus on why you played 14.d4?? The move makes no sense strategically or tactically, which leads me to believe you are either playing too quickly, too slowly (and getting into time trouble), calculating too little, overestimating your opponent's chances and thinking you're going to lose the pawn anyway, or something else. Figure out why you made the mistake and then work on not making it again.

Comment: Also, this isn't a position you should be resigning in. Yes, it's objectively lost, but it isn't the type of win that's going to come easy for a lower rated opponent and one of those lost positions where if you play on funny things can happen.

Comment: There's a recent thread on GMs who are hard to beat.  This is the sort of position they could hold.  You can do it if you're tenacious enough.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: 1...Rh2 2.Rh1! and White will exchange at least a pair of rooks, **gain control of the h-file** and manage to safely introduce the last rook into the game, while keeping his king safe. *Stockfish* gives the current evaluation, which is "White stands better" since Black has a pawn for a piece, but can not evaluate the position properly **on the long run**. The 2.Kd2?! it chose over simple 2.Rh1!, which liquidates the attack, is the good proof. Best regards.

Comment: This is question number 1000!

Comment: @BroSlow 14. d4 was meant to develop my bishop.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff after 19. Be3 Rh2 20. Rh1!, Black retorts with 20...Qxe3+ 21. Kf1 Qxf2#.  I don't see how White wins after this.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: I missed that one... I do not have time at the moment to fully analyze the position, which my blunder can confirm. After I get some spare time I will post an answer that thoroughly analyses the game. Best regards.

Comment: Can't believe this hasn't been said: You let Black's rook out when you traded your knight fora  bishop. Getting the bishop off that diagonal wasn't important because Black castled queen-side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things leap out at me:

1. Moderate error: After 8...Bh5, you're a piece up but you're not done developing and your knight on e4 is unprotected. Reasonable moves (I'm sure there are others) include 9.d3, supporting your knight and allowing your bishop to develop; 9.Re1, centralizing your rook and supporting your knight; and 9.Ng3, kicking Black's bishop and moving your knight to a safe square. Instead you played 9.g4, weakening your king's position and forcing the Black bishop to a place where it attacks your knight.
2. Huge error: You're still doing OK as of 13...hxg6, but your h3-pawn is under attack. (Note that this wouldn't have been an issue if you hadn't played 9.g4.) The simplest defense is 14.Qf3 but 14.Kg2 is possible too. Instead you let Black's rook capture on h3 and now your king is under severe attack.

You could have defended against the ensuing attack better, but I'm not going to bother with that because the way to win games like these is to not even let it get to that point.

Comment: Yea... 9. g4  was such a bad move.

Answer (score 4):

I think that after

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nf6 4. Nc3 a6 5. Bxc6 dxc6 6. O-O Nxe4 7. Nxe4 Bg4 8. h3 Bh5 9.Ng3 Bg6 10.Nxe5 Qd6 11.Nxg6 hxg6 12.Re1+ Be7 13.Qg4
```

it is lights out for black. In general, avoid moving pawns in front of your king after it has castled kingside or queenside. Try to catch your opponents king while it is still in the center.

Comment: `In general, avoid moving pawns in front of your king after it has castled kingside or queenside.` You KIDding?

Comment: @BroSlow If you have an additional question, that's fine. But "you kidding?" isn't very helpful.

Comment: Guess you missed the capitalization.

Comment: @BroSlow Please explain a bit more :) is it the King's Indian Defense you are talking about and you mean that g7-g6 is a strong move in those positions?

Comment: Yes I mean the King's Indian Defense. Nope, just joking, obviously bad here.

Comment: @BroSlow Well, I meant that g7-g6 is simply part of the KID and thus there is nothing wrong with it, and I agree with that fully. My point was that in general, one should avoid playing h2-h3 and definitely avoid g2-g4 unless the position is such that it is indeed possible to defend your king afterwards. Of course, with the queens off the board and strong control (or no need to control) f4 and h4, then g2-g4 is more playable.

Comment: Perhaps it is more accurate to say: "Avoid moving pawns in front of your king in open positions", of course there are exceptions to this too, but they are not that common. In closed positions, like KID, pawn storm is very common, almost thematic.

Comment: Yes, there is a line in the KID where black pushes the pawns in front of his king with abandon, but the reason we immediately think of that line is that it's the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Three (bad) things happened:

1. You weakened your kingside by playing `g4`.
2. Black castled O-O-O, to take advantage of number 1, while protecting his king behind the phalanx of (doubled) pawns.
3. The worst thing that happened was that `13. Nxg6 hxg6` opened up the h file for Black in front of a rook that had not moved. You should have moved the N back to `f3` to keep a defender in place, and to keep the h file closed. On move 14, your best chance was the defensive `Qf3`, rather than the developing `d4`. You had a won game up to move 13, and a questionable game after `14...Rxh3` (Black could have played differently than he did and gotten a perpetual check to compensate for his piece down.)

Comment: If he plays Nf3, Black has 13...h5!? Plus the bishop on g6 is too strong. 13. Nxg6 is correct. 14. Qf3 or 14. Kg2 was required.

Comment: @Wes: If Black plays 13...h5!?, I play 14. Nh2, supporting the pawn on g4, and eventually the pawn on f3. These two pawns dampen the B on g6. But White could have saved himself on move 14 with Qf3 or Kg2.

Comment: After Nh2, hxg4 opens the h-file anyway. So Nf3 doesn't really stop black from opening the h-file. Better to play Nxg6 and get rid of that strong bishop. Also, note that after hxg4 you can't play hxg4, because of Qxh2+!

Comment: @Wes: If Black plays hxg4, I play Qxg4 CHECK and bring my queen to the defense.

Comment: structurally, its worse for White because of the isolated pawns

Comment: @Wes: If Black plays hxg4, I play Qxg4 CHECK and capture the forked bishop.

Comment: f5 protects the bishop!

Comment: @Wes: The bishop can interpose on f5, but where's the guard? It's not the h pawn, because it captured on g4, rather than g6. Black's queen is on a black square (no diagonal guard), and on d6, not d5 (no horizontal guard). No vertical guard on the f file, either.

Comment: I mean pawn to f5, of course. The queen on d6 then supports the bishop on g6.